# Testing controllers in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockmvc

I want to write a functional test by calling some controllers.

```
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext ctx;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        ....

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/perform/1")).andReturn();
        Map<String, Object> model = mvcResult.getModelAndView().getModel();

        //assert....

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/perform/2")).andReturn();
        Map<String, Object> model = mvcResult.getModelAndView().getModel();

        //assert....
```

After perform/1 is called a User model is stored in the session:

```
 @Controller
 @SessionAttributes("user")
 public class CoreController {
```

I would like to call perform/2 immediate after perform/1 in the same test but it seems that user = null then.
Is this normal behavior?

How can I accomplish this? How can I write a functional test with Spring controllers?

Comment: I don't see any login, how are you populating the user session in the first run?

Comment: I don't signin here. I just add an empty User object. This works fine in tomcat. In the second call I can get the user from the session via @ModelAttribute User user parameter.

Comment: I believe you need to autowire a `MockHttpSession` object and set the User model that is obtained after perform/1 to the `MockHttpSession` object prior to calling perform/2.

Comment: I suggest you visit this site [http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/)